# Grails Basic Authentication credentials passed in URL

Tags: authentication, grails, authorization

I'm trying to access some URL to fetch a JSON file from my Grails application, but could not find a way to pass authentication credentials.

I'm trying this code to get pass authentication

```
String url = 'http://urlThatIwantToGoTo.com'
String ID = 'my_ID'
String PW = 'my_PW'
String website = 'http://my_ID:my_PW@urlThatIwantToGoTo.com'

String jsonFile = new JsonSlurper().parseText(new URL(website).text)
```

But I'm still getting 401 errors.

Comment: Well I am pretty sure the URL you are trying to access is wrong. The URL is wrong. Firstly when you use a colon it specifies the port number. You seem to be passing a password.  Please refer to the API properly. I think it could be something along the lines of `http://urlThatIwantToGoTo.com?usernameParam=myId&pwParam=pwd`.  If you are trying to fetch something from your app that does not require authentication, then you can use the security filter to try and whiteList it. There are several solutions on stackoverflow too.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm not getting what you are saying...
If you type in http://my_ID:my_PW@urlThatIwantToGoTo.com above it works on normal browsers(no need to type in the id and the password)
But when you type in 'http://urlThatIwantToGoTo.com?usernameParam=myId&pwParam=pwd', it still requires an id and the password.

Comment: **http://www.cs.rutgers.edu/~watrous/user-pass-url.html** is where I got help from

Comment: The protocol you are supposed to use is FTP. Not HTTP